# VueJs and transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions, vuejs3

I have several child components rendered by a v-for

```
<div v-for="(pass) in scoringPass" :key="pass.decision">
    <Pass :pass="pass"/>
  </div>
```

And inside those, I have the transition tag

```
<template>
<h4 @click="onShowClick">Scoring Pass {{ pass.index }}</h4>
  <transition name="onShow">
<div class="submain" v-if="onShow">
  <div class="mainSub">
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Decision</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.decision }}</div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="item in pass.motif" :key="item" class="info">
      <h5>Motif</h5>
      <div>
        <div>Emprunteur : {{ item.emprunteur }}</div>
        <div>Membre du groupe : {{ item.groupMember }}</div>
        <div>Grille de pouvoirs : {{ item.powerGrid }}</div>
        <div>Info : {{ item.info }}</div>
        <div>Info : {{ item.info2 }}</div>
        <div>Score B : {{ item.score }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Score</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.score }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainSub">
    <div class="info">
      <h5>No emp</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.noEmp }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Seq</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.seq }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Limit Type</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.limitType }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Type produit</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.productType }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Type crédit</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.creditType }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Decision</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.decision2 }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Motif</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.motif2 }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Product Grade</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.productGrade }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5>Approved Limit - Offer 1</h5>
      <div class="infoDetails">{{ pass.approvedlimit }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</transition>
</template>
```

CSS :

```
.onShow-leave-active,
.onShow-enter-active {
transition: 0.5s;
}
.onShow-enter {
transform: translateY(100%);
}
.onShow-leave-to {
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Currently the enter animation is not working and can't figure out why. I am new with `Vue` and even more so with `Vue transition and animation`.

In the end, I would like to have the child components "deploying themselves" instead of sliding in while pushing the component below them.

The "translate" was for trying to make something working at least.

Thank you !

Comment: What's the "onShow" boolean? Do you except the component to animate when the `scoringPass` list is updated, or when the `onShow` boolean switches inside each component?

Comment: The onShow boolean is to display the child component and I want the animation to launch when the boolean = true. It becomes true when you use the onShowClick method.

Comment: Ok, in the inspector, do you see some classes applied when you click your button? Also, does the `<transition>` element has only one child element or several?

Comment: Several, it is quite long but I can edit the post.

Comment: And in the inspector, I can only see the class added by the transition itself.

Comment: So that's the problem. A `<transition>` component can only have one child, typically the one that is conditionally rendered so it can be animated. Try with a wrapper that encapsulate all the elements you want to animate for example, with the `v-if` on that wrapper

Comment: I edited the post with the whole child component

Comment: Ok, so it does have only 1 direct child (grand-child doesn't matter) ^^ Could you try to make a minimal reproduction on codesandbox or Codepen? I don't see anything wrong here.

The classes added by the `<transition>` component, what are they? Something like `onShow-enter`?

Comment: Yes, I added the CSS at the end of the post.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-sunset-g3bv85?file=/src/App.vue CodeSandBox with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `.onShow-enter-from` instead of `.onShow-enter`

[your demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cache-47pkeu?file=/src/components/Pass.vue)

Comment: That did it for the enter transition. Thanks ! Do you know how I could make it "deploy" rather than slide in ?